# Saving a resource (image etc) relative to application root and using it back in a Servlet / Jsp

Tags: jsp, web-applications, servlets, root

I have this use case for which I am generating an image in the getPost method of servlet.
I was saving the image in the local file system at /tmp/xyz.jpg and then doing something like

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<title>Example</title>");
out.println("<body><h2>Graph is :</h2>");
out.println("<img src='/tmp/TimeSeriesChart.jpg'></body>");
out.println("</html>");
```

Naturally the image did not get displayed when I hit the URL (to call servlet).

The reason I think was that img src is calculating against the Application's Root not fileSystem's Root.

So to summarize I want to be able to save the image at a proper place relative to Application Root , access the image and display it.

Q1. How to find the Application Root within the servlet.  So that I can save the image rightly.

Q2. How advisable is to set the content as image and then read it as bytes and display : 
    http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetImage.html

Comment: Meanwhile I am trying the second way and if servlet context is going to help me or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ans1: ServletContext.getRealPath() will give you the app root location.

Ans2: Nothing wrong in having a servlet, but Container doing that would handle the following cases as well:

1. If-Modified-Since, sends SC_NOT_MODIFIED response
2. Caching the image data in container for subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks I have tried the second way (converting to bytes and set content type as image) and it worked like a charm. I will try yours now

Comment: Yours Also Worked and this is the best way :).
I used 
`String path = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("");`.       
`fileName = path + "TimeSeriesChart.jpg"` and then used '<image src="TimeSeriesChart.jpg" />'
** DO NOT USE <img src=fileName >. src will calculate every path relative to root so just the filename is required